# How to generate installer application delphi xe7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have just finish a small delphi xe7 application, which need some dll file for working. How should i create the application installer .exe for installing such application in other pc?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Like David H. said this type of question can become very opinionated.  Also the answer to your question will depend somewhat on the target OS of the "other pc".  In my experience I have had good luck using a free product call NSIS that will create setup applications fairly easily.  [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download)

Comment: There are many many possible tools. Which one is best for you depends on your requirements. Which we cannot see. So nobody is in a position to offer a recommendation. For instance, perhaps you have a requirement to produce an MSI package. Then tools like Inno are no good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is free, easy to use and can correctly handle all current OS's flavours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have XE7, so I'm not aware if there's an installation generator shiped with it or not. If not, I advise you to learn about [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's a free setup wizard generator, that has a scripting language similar to Pascal (PascalScript), so it's very welcoming to Delphi programmers. There's a lot of info about it around the net and its documentantion is complete and clear.